# An object with the same key already exists in the ObjectStateManager

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, many-to-many

can't save **many-to-many** property to database.

error detail:

> An object with the same key already exists in the ObjectStateManager.
>   The ObjectStateManager cannot track multiple objects with the same
>   key.

i've tried to save the property in this action method:

```
       [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult Edit(UserRole role)
        {
            var permissionNameList=  (from per in _db.Permissions
                                               select per.Name).Distinct().ToList();
            foreach(var name in permissionNameList)
            {
                role.Permissions.Add(new permission(name, oper));
            }

            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                _db.Entry(role).State = System.Data.EntityState.Modified;
                _db.SaveChanges();
                return RedirectToAction("Index");
            }
            return View(role);
        }
```

the database table structure is like this:

3 table

`userRole`-`permissionsInRoles`-`permission`

```
CREATE TABLE newsmonitoringmanagement.permission
(
Id          INT NOT NULL auto_increment,
Name        VARCHAR (50) NOT NULL,
Description VARCHAR (250) NULL,
Operations  INT NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (Id),
UNIQUE KEY UK_permissionIdentity (Name, Operations)
);
```

in db-context :

```
        modelBuilder.Entity<UserRole>()
            .HasMany(usrRole => usrRole.Permissions)
            .WithMany(permisn => permisn.Roles)
            .Map(m =>
            {
                m.ToTable("permissionsInRoles");
                m.MapLeftKey("RoleId");
                m.MapRightKey("PermissionId");
            });

        modelBuilder.Entity<Permission>()
            .HasMany(per => per.Roles)
            .WithMany(role => role.Permissions)
            .Map(m =>
            {
                m.ToTable("permissionsInRoles");
                m.MapLeftKey("PermissionId");
                m.MapRightKey("RoleId");
            });
```

---

an update, new code down here can work,
but seems wired, because the arg `role`'s `permissions` property is `empty`

```
var permissionNameList = (from per in _db.Permissions
                                  select per.Name).Distinct().ToList();
        var realRole = (from r in _db.UserRoles
                        where r.Id == role.Id
                        select r).First();

        foreach (var perm in realRole.Permissions)
        {
            var opert = Convert.ToInt32(Request.Form[perm.Name + "_op"]);
            if (perm.Name.InList(permissionNameList))
            {
                perm.Operations = opert;
            }
        }

        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            _db.Entry(realRole).State = System.Data.EntityState.Modified;
            _db.SaveChanges();
        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

modefy code to retrieve from database then it works.

```
public ActionResult Edit(UserRole role)
{
    var permissionNameList = (from per in _db.Permissions
                              select per.Name).Distinct().ToList();
    var realRole = (from r in _db.UserRoles
                    where r.Id == role.Id
                    select r).First();

    foreach (var perm in realRole.Permissions)
    {
        var opert = Convert.ToInt32(Request.Form[perm.Name + "_op"]);
        if (perm.Name.InList(permissionNameList))
        {
            perm.Operations = opert;
        }
    }

    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        _db.Entry(realRole).State = System.Data.EntityState.Modified;
        _db.SaveChanges();
    }

    this.TempData["msg"] = "[EditRolePermissions]Saved Role Id " + role.Id;
    return RedirectToAction("Details/" + role.Id);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

is `name field` a unique field in permissions table?
if yes then obviously you cant make a new permission with the same `name` as a previous one and thats what you are doing.
EDIT:- cant you just add the permissions you are getting from database as it is
i mean is there really a special need to create new permission
something like this

```
var permissionList=  (from per in _db.Permissions
                                               select per).Distinct();

            foreach(var permission in permissionList)
            {

                var opert = Convert.ToInt32(Request.Form[name + "_op"]);
                //var per=new Permission();
                //per.Name=name;
                permmission.Operations=opert;
                role.Permissions.Add(permission);
            }
```

Comment: pls see my update. UNIQUE KEY UK_permissionIdentity (Name, Operations)

Comment: i've changed the `Operations` property, so i need to save all these things back to database.  var opert = Convert.ToInt32(Request.Form[name + "_op"]);

Comment: see my edit.. if you dont need to create a new permission operation can be edited easily